Two jars having similar package structure. Wrong class being called during runtime
I have following springboot application
Parent
-- ReportAnalytics which has the main method
-- diffToolv1 (has getDifference REST api end point) : dependency on jar1
-- diffToolv2 (has getDifferenceV2 REST api end point) : dependency on jar2

jar1 and jar2 both have a package inspector.
Now when I am calling a method in diffToolv1, it is referring to class of inspector package from jar2. This might be because when springboot is initialized, jar2 is loaded before jar1.
I cannot modify package name in the dependencies.
What are my options?
Things which I tried:
chatgpt gave different strategies but those would not work. Here is the list:

Classpath Ordering: I want both jars in classpath
Exclude or Remove Conflicting JAR: Same as above
Use Fully Qualified Class Names: I wish I could use jar names in import statements
Custom Classloader: Both the jars need to be loaded. So I am not sure.
Rename Packages: They are not my packages. I can't modify them.
Debugging: I have verified that jar2 classes are getting called from diffToolv1.


You should rename the package/class because that is an invite for problems. The already suggest usage to rename during build time is only a temporary solution because that makes your build process more complex than needed.. If those pacakage is coming from a dependency my question is: How does it happen? Do you use two versions of the same dependency? (That sounds more weird and also wrong).. If you have different artifacts you should qualify your import statements... if only a part of the package name is the same? Or do you have really the same package name ? Please give more details...

Use a tool like https://github.com/shevek/jarjar  to rename one of the classes at build time. This can be a good solution if you don't have control over the source code and cant change the name of the class.

Do not use that. It is ancient old and is not usable in Maven. If you like to use that kind of approach better use  maven-shade-plugin
